# Programmatically change HubSection Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to change a Hubsection as if you moved it with your finger per code? E.g. I have three HubSections, I click a button in HubSection3 and it changes to HubSection1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assign both your hub and your sections names, then in your code-behind you can do something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyHub.ScrollToSection(HubSection1);
}
```

However from a UI perspective, I personally wouldn't drive the navigation with a button in this way. As generally, the purpose of a hub is to display content in a similar style to that of a magazine, allowing the user to flick through the content at their discretion.

Comment: Thanks, perfectly worked. Yeah i'm new to Windows Phone so I'm just trying things out.